# Int to English words in Java

Tags: java

Here I am to ask something weird.

I would like to ask that is there any method/logic by which we can convert an integer value to a string value containing the English words for the number?

E.g user inputs 22 and gets the output twenty two or two.

Thanks

Comment: Google copies from forums and Q&A's such as this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) code, it might be what you're looking for. For example, inside the main method if we had:

```
System.out.println(convert(22));
```

Output:

```
twenty two
```

---

***EDIT*** I've reproduced the code below, cleaning up the formatting a bit (main-method is at the bottom):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class EnglishNumberToWords {

    private static final String[] tensNames = { "", " ten", " twenty",
            " thirty", " forty", " fifty", " sixty", " seventy", " eighty",
            " ninety" };

    private static final String[] numNames = { "", " one", " two", " three",
            " four", " five", " six", " seven", " eight", " nine", " ten",
            " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen", " fourteen", " fifteen",
            " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen" };

    private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {
        String soFar;

        if (number % 100 < 20) {
            soFar = numNames[number % 100];
            number /= 100;
        } else {
            soFar = numNames[number % 10];
            number /= 10;

            soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
            number /= 10;
        }
        if (number == 0)
            return soFar;
        return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
    }

    public static String convert(long number) {
        // 0 to 999 999 999 999
        if (number == 0) {
            return "zero";
        }

        String snumber = Long.toString(number);

        // pad with "0"
        String mask = "000000000000";
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
        snumber = df.format(number);

        // XXXnnnnnnnnn
        int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0, 3));
        // nnnXXXnnnnnn
        int millions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3, 6));
        // nnnnnnXXXnnn
        int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6, 9));
        // nnnnnnnnnXXX
        int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9, 12));

        String tradBillions;
        switch (billions) {
        case 0:
            tradBillions = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions) + " billion ";
            break;
        default:
            tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions) + " billion ";
        }
        String result = tradBillions;

        String tradMillions;
        switch (millions) {
        case 0:
            tradMillions = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions) + " million ";
            break;
        default:
            tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions) + " million ";
        }
        result = result + tradMillions;

        String tradHundredThousands;
        switch (hundredThousands) {
        case 0:
            tradHundredThousands = "";
            break;
        case 1:
            tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
            break;
        default:
            tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands)
                    + " thousand ";
        }
        result = result + tradHundredThousands;

        String tradThousand;
        tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
        result = result + tradThousand;

        // remove extra spaces!
        return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert(22));  // "twenty two"
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because this link only answer becomes invalid as soon as the linked page moves or is deleted.  An answer should contain enough info to standalone referencing links for additional info (if necessary).

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Alright, I've included the relevant code - see edit.

Comment: We can do it using arrays but any other way to do it... I mean any predefined function or something?

Comment: @Shivam There is no pre-defined Java package to do it unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer works, it would probably be best to use already-implemented functions to perform this. [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org) contains a class `com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat` that can be used to perform this operation.  It also supports languages other than English, and the reverse operation, parsing a text string to integer values.

Here is an example, assuming that we have the [ICU4J dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j) in the classpath:

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedNumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

RuleBasedNumberFormat nf = new RuleBasedNumberFormat (Locale.UK, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
nf.format(24);
// The result is "twenty-four"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution that can convert whole integer range in java to hinglish notation

```
    String h1[] = { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Tweleve", "Thirteen",
                "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen",
                "Nineteen" };
        String h2[] = { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy",
                "Eighty", "Ninety" };
        String h3[] = { "Hundred", "Thousand", "Lakh", "Crore", "Arab" };

public String parseToHinglishNotation(int num) {
        String word = "";

        if (num < 0) {
            word += "Minus ";
            num = -num;
        }

        if (num < 20) {
            word += h1[num];
        } else if (num < 100) {
            int temp = num / 10 - 2;
            word += h2[temp];

            temp = num % 10;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        } else if (num < 1000) {
            int temp = num / 100;
            word += parseToHinglishNotation(temp) + " " + h3[0];

            temp = num % 100;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        } else if (num < 100000) {
            int temp = num / 1000;
            word += parseToHinglishNotation(temp) + " " + h3[1];

            temp = num % 1000;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        } else if (num < 10000000) {
            int temp = num / 100000;
            word += parseToHinglishNotation(temp) + " " + h3[2];

            temp = num % 100000;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        } else if (num < 1000000000) {
            int temp = num / 10000000;
            word += parseToHinglishNotation(temp) + " " + h3[3];

            temp = num % 10000000;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        } else if (num <= 2147483647) {
            int temp = num / 1000000000;
            word += parseToHinglishNotation(temp) + " " + h3[4];

            temp = num % 1000000000;
            if (temp > 0) {
                word += " " + parseToHinglishNotation(temp);
            }
        }

        return word;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kind of old, but I recently came up with my own solution and figured it might be worth sharing. The primary function `numToWords` takes any `Integer` between 1 and 9999 (inclusive) and outputs its corresponding English words, followed by the `String` of digits in parenthesis.

Example: If `Integer x = 2614;`, `numToText(x);` returns `"Two Thousand Six Hundred Fourteen (2614)"`:

The digit-equivalent words are stored in HashMaps depending on whether they're multiples of 1 or 10 (e.g. `6 --> "Six"`, `60 --> "Sixty"`) while the teens are handled independently with a `switch` statement.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Converter{

    public Converter(){
        hm1.put(0, "");
        hm1.put(1, "One");
        hm1.put(2, "Two");
        hm1.put(3, "Three");
        hm1.put(4, "Four");
        hm1.put(5, "Five");
        hm1.put(6, "Six");
        hm1.put(7, "Seven");
        hm1.put(8, "Eight");
        hm1.put(9, "Nine");

        hm10.put(0, "");
        hm10.put(1, "");
        hm10.put(2, "Twenty ");
        hm10.put(3, "Thirty ");
        hm10.put(4, "Fourty ");
        hm10.put(5, "Fifty ");
        hm10.put(6, "Sixty ");
        hm10.put(7, "Seventy ");
        hm10.put(8, "Eighty ");
        hm10.put(9, "Ninety ");
    }

    public static String numToWords(Integer x){
            // Obtain a char[] of the Integer to analyze each digit.
        String s = x.toString();
        char[] cArray = s.toCharArray();

            // Refer to the length of the Integer as its final index.
        int l = cArray.length-1;
        String retStr = "";
            // The loop counts backwards from the right-most digit. 
        for(int i = l; i >= 0; i--){
                // Determine the numeric value at the left-most index, then move rightward.
                // This setup is attributed to the nuances of the English language.
            int j = Character.getNumericValue(cArray[l-i]);
                //
            if(i == 3){
                retStr += hm1.get(j);
                retStr += " Thousand ";
            } else if(i == 2){
                retStr += hm1.get(j);
                retStr += " Hundred ";    
            } else if(i == 1){
                    //If the 10s digit is 1, the final word is 10 <= x <= 19.
                if(j == 1){
                    String tens = "";
                        // Check the 1s digit to determine x (10 <= x <= 19)
                    switch(Character.getNumericValue(cArray[l])){
                        case 0: tens = "Ten";                   
                                break;  
                        case 1: tens = "Eleven";                    
                                break;
                        case 2: tens = "Twelve";
                                break;
                        case 3: tens = "Thirteen";
                                break;
                        case 4: tens = "Fourteen";
                                break;
                        case 5: tens = "Fifteen";
                                break;
                        case 6: tens = "Sixteen";
                                break;
                        case 7: tens = "Seventeen";
                                break;
                        case 8: tens = "Eighteen";
                                break;
                        case 9: tens = "Nineteen";
                                break;
                        }
                    i = -1; // Ensure it's the last word by indexing out of the loop.
                    retStr += tens;
                } else {
                        //If the 10s digit is 2 <= x <= 9, the 10s word is 20 <= x <= 90.
                    retStr += hm10.get(j);
                }
            } else if(i == 0){
                retStr += hm1.get(j);
            }
        }
        return retStr + " (" + x + ") ";
    }

    private HashMap<Integer, String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> hm10 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}
```