# Converting Numbers to Words and reexecuting if invalid input

Tags: java

Im trying to Convert numbers to words from 0-100 only and how do i reexecute the program if it didnt meet the conditions without extiting the program.
if i input 55, i want to output Fifty-Five but if i type numbers that are not in 0-100, it will output "you should input 0-100 only try again" then it will automatically go to "input number between 0-100 only"

```
package convertnumbertowords;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConvertNumberToWords {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input number between 0-100 only ");
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    while (num1 <= -1 && num1 >= 101 ){
        if(num1 <= 100 && num1 >= 0){
            System.out.println("The "+num1+" in words is "+ 
            Integer.toString(num1));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You should input 0-100 only Try Again");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Insert `int num1 = sc.nextInt();` to the `while` loop. This won't give you the expected results though, `Integer.toString()` won't change `55` to `Fifty-Five`, it will just change it to `'55'`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, is to keep the words within an array, separate it to ones, and tens.
E.g.:

```
String ones[] = { " ", " One", " Two", " Three", " Four", " Five", " Six", " Seven", " Eight", " Nine", " Ten"," Eleven", " Twelve", " Thirteen", " Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", " Seventeen", " Eighteen"," Nineteen" };
```

The reason why I kept the ones[0] as empty, so it'll be easy to understand, ones[1] = one

```
String tens[] = { " ", " ", " Twenty", " Thirty", " Forty", " Fifty", " Sixty", "Seventy", " Eighty", " Ninety" };
```

I kept the 0, 10 as empty because I have it declared in the ones.

Based on my example,  if it's less than that just use ones[number]. If it's more than 19 , I would suggest to divide it with ten to get the word for its tens word and then modulus(%) the number with 10 to get its ones word. All the best in cracking it, My suggestion may not be prefect but hope it will give you some idea

Comment: how can i connect this to integer? like if i input 55 how will it convert to fifty-five?

Comment: So for my idea if it's 55: If we're to try as `tens[55/10] +" - " + ones[55%10]` , it should give out fivety - five

Would this help you ? Found this as well
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java

Answer (score 0):

To keep until correct input is entered you first take an input -> check if it is wrong -> If yes then prompt user again otherwise move to next step. In code it will look like this

```
// Ask for input
System.out.println("Input number between 0-100 only ");
int num = sc.nextInt();
// Check if input is incorrect
while (num > 100 || num < 0) {
    // If input is incorrect prompt user again
    System.out.println("You should input 0-100 only Try Again");
    // Update num and check until unser enters a num within the range
    num = sc.nextInt();  
}
```

Comment: so there will be two while loops?

Comment: No. After this you won't need any validation.

Comment: @iDevdevdev To convert int to Words take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219091/int-to-english-words-in-java