# How to translate a currency number to french words using XSLT? My input is XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to translate a currency number to french words using XSLT

Input:

```
         <AMOUNTS>
         <VALUE>123.56</VALUE>
         </AMOUNTS>
```

Required Output: cent vingt-trois dollars et cinquante-six centièmes

I searched for inbuilt functions but cannot see any information. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think you will find a pre-built function for this. If you're patient you can try building one with lots of ifs and choose! By the way your example text output is missing six cents

Answer (score 2):

`format-integer` in XPath 3 has support for the `w` format specifier and takes a language attribute, thus, if various languages are supported, the expression

```
('en', 'de', 'es', 'fr')!format-integer(123, 'w', .)
```

can output (for instance, tested with Saxon PE 9.9)

```
one hundred and twenty three
 
ein­hundert­drei­und­zwanzig
 
ciento veintitrés
 
cent vingt-trois
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the syntax using XSLT?

Comment: @DanRV, do you use an XSLT 3 processor? Have you checked it supports different languages specifiers for `format-integer`? The syntax is e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="format-integer(data, 'w', 'fr')"/>` where data contains an integer number.

Comment: If your XSLT processor doesn't support check whether the host language/platform has a library supporting it, like ICU in Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192857/252228.

Comment: Hi I am trying this but its only converting into english                                                                                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="AMOUNTS/VALUE"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-integer(123, 'w', 'fr')"/>
<xsl:variable name="n" select="VALUE" />

<xsl:value-of select="$n"/>



</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output: one hundred and twenty three

Comment: With Saxon PE or EE?