# Replace a string inside square brackets with multipe values

Tags: java, string

I have String like below.

```
String test3 = "'[47]GSA - Format'!$X$13-[49]Summary!$H$7/1000-[51]Summary!$H$6/1000+150";
```

I want to replace the values inside square brackets. Like

[47] with Fourty Seven.xlsx

[49] with Fourty Nine.xlsx

[51] with Fifty One.xlsx

I am expecting string in this way

Fourty Seven.xlsxGSA - Format'!$X$13-Fourty Nine.xlsxSummary!$H$7/1000-Fifty One.xlsxSummary!$H$6/1000+150

I tried below:

```
for (String key : keys) {
        String value = dataMap.get(key);
        value = formatValue(value);
        // test3 = test3.replaceAll(" *\\[\\d+\\] *", value);
        // test3 = test3.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");
        test3 = test3.replaceAll("\\[" + key + "\\]", value);
        // test3 = test3.replaceAll(key, value);
    }
```

Replacing not seems to be working the way as expected.

How do I replace all occurrences individually of it?

Comment: One easy way is to have the keys include the brackets.  `[47]` instead of `47`.

Comment: See [Int to English words in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219091/int-to-english-words-in-java)

Comment: Using [Int to English words in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13219091) we could use `String result = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)]").matcher(test3).replaceAll(m -> EnglishNumberToWords.convert(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)))+".xlsx");` which would produce `'forty seven.xlsxGSA - Format'!$X$13-forty nine.xlsxSummary!$H$7/1000-fifty one.xlsxSummary!$H$6/1000+150` (numbers are in lower-case, you can write your own method to first change first letters to upper case before using it in replacement).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pshemo . It is not about converting them into english letters it could be any name. like summary.xlsx etc... 
[47] with Fourty Seven.xlsx

[49] with Summary.xlsx

[51] with Music.xlsx or anything

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I included the brackets... when i go for replace all..it is replacing all key.
The value of [47] getting replaced for [49] and [51] also.

Comment: If you have `public static String yourMethod(String number){...}` which can map number found in your string to value you want, then you can use `String result = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)]").matcher(test3).replaceAll(m -> yourMethod(m.group(1)));`.